# Laravel container returning multiple Singleton instances

Tags: php, singleton, laravel-5.7

I've created a `CustomProvider`, added it to the `app.php` array of providers and registered a class as singleton:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\ReserveCart;

class CustomProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
    */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('App\ReserveCart', function($app){
            return new ReserveCart;
        });
    }
}
```

but everytime I request for the object with `$rc = resolve('App\ReserveCart');` it keeps giving me different instances of the object instead of a single one (I've done some echo tracking).

Also tried passing the dependency to methods acording to Laravel Documentation. e.g

```
public function foo(App\ReserveCart $rc){
    //
}
```

but the issue persists.

Answer (score 2):

Is the output below same ?

```
$rc = resolve('App\ReserveCart');
$rc1 = resolve('App\ReserveCart');
dd(spl_object_hash($rc), spl_object_hash($rc1));
```

Comment: Yes it is, but as soon as I make another http request, the output changes. Just for testing purposes in the UserController put this:
  
 `public function show($id)
    {
        //return User::find($id);
        $rc = resolve('App\ReserveCart');
        $rc1 = resolve('App\ReserveCart');
        echo dd(spl_object_hash($rc), spl_object_hash($rc1));
    }`

and then everytime I make for example `/users/2` the output is the same, but as soon as I change the request for `/users/3` the output changes in comparison to `/users/2` but it is the same object in the /users/3 context

Comment: Yes it is the right behavior, the `singleton` in laravel just mean you will get the same object in one request, if you make another request, you will get the different one. Because in php every request is a totally new context, different from some other language like `java`, `nodejs` or `golang`.

Comment: I see... Many thanks for your help! Any suggestions on how to achieve the behavior I want for the `ReserveCart` object? The reason I need it is for sharing data across different views that represent a multi-step process of a reserve

Comment: You can implement this by [Cache](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/cache), or if you are using the same session, you can just use [Session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session), which is easier to use.